# How to remove the "O()" in series from sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to draw Taylor expansion of a function, for example: sin

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
m, x = symbols("m x")
plot(*Array([2, 4, 6]).applyfunc(lambda m: sin(x).series(x0=0, n=m)), (x, -pi/2, pi/2))
```

But , since `Array([2, 4, 6]).applyfunc(lambda m: sin(x).series(x0=0, n=m)` gives out

[image]

sympy can't plot them.

So I wonder is there a way to remove the `O(x^n)`? In Mathematica, I can use `Normal` to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to remove the O:

```
In [5]: s = sin(x).series(x)                                                                                                      

In [6]: s                                                                                                                         
Out[6]: 
     3     5        
    x     x     ⎛ 6⎞
x - ── + ─── + O⎝x ⎠
    6    120        

In [7]: s.removeO()                                                                                                               
Out[7]: 
  5    3    
 x    x     
─── - ── + x
120   6     

In [8]: s.getO()                                                                                                                  
Out[8]: 
 ⎛ 6⎞
O⎝x ⎠
```